# How to obtain a URL parameter in the application component

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there some way to get the hero id parameter from the `ApplicationComponent`?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: I wrote an article, check Story IV: How to get all URL parameters? It might be helpful -  https://blog.angularindepth.com/lessons-learned-while-upgrading-from-angularjs-ui-router-to-angular-router-13c7cb76938c

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the route params from your root component (it does not have a route).

I can think of two options to solve this:

#### 1. Parse it yourself (not very robust)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map((e: NavigationEnd) => e.urlAfterRedirects),
      // parse the url as needed
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

#### 2. Share the params in a dedicated service (more effort)

Create a service (in the example `RouteParamsService`) that stores the current ids. Then access the id in your `AppComponent`.

**HeroComponent**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private paramsService: RouteParamsService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => this.paramsService.set('heroId', params.get('id')));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.paramsService.delete('heroId');
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
constructor(private paramsService: RouteParamsService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.paramsService.params.subscribe(params => params['heroId']);
}
```

Comment: this does not work, since the activated route encapsulates the parameters that correspond to each component. try using parent but the application component does not have any parent since it includes all the components

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. The answer is now updated.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it is somewhat annoying that angular can not access the parameters I guess it is something of design

Comment: Still having problems? :-)

Answer (score 0):

**returns an array with the identifiers of the urls**

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname.match(/(\d+)/g))
console.log('questions/52706460/how-to-obtain-a-url-parameter-in-the-application-component'.match(/(\d+)/g))
```